# Copy and Paste based on column header

Tags: excel, vba

**The issue:**

I have a **working file** to collect sales input from various sources. Once completed, I want to capture the state of this data into an **analytics file** that has some automated functions. Due to the amount of **working files** and every working file having their own **analysis file**, I want to automate the copy-pasting between both files with a macro.

**State of the data:**

Both the **working file** and **analytics file** ***initially*** have exactly the same structure, except the **analytics file** having multiple copies to paste multiple states of the **working file**. Also, an user of the working file may **add** one or multiple columns in the **working file** in case he/she needs it. I'm however only interested in capturing the standard structure and ignore the rest. The top 11 rows never change and new data will only be entered from row 12 onward.

**My solution:**

In the 1st row I used a code to identify the same column headers and want to use a macro in the **Analytics file** to **Select** and **Open** the **working file** and copy-paste the latest version of the data over.

I've added a working file with the macro as an example. A few more remarks:

**Link to files:**
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1u7IS_FtBmocZGHi19io-zxyAKmgMK2HJ

- The yellow highlighted columns are there to indicate that a user added a column. I **don't** want to copy-paste these columns.
- The Macro refers to Sheet(2) directly since that is the official number and remains fixed to allow users to change the sheet name.
- The macro is created by me through combing the internet and combining solutions. Unfortunately there remains parts I don't follow :) Maybe someone here will recognize a solution from themselves.
- The macro also count the amount of columns to find out how long it must compare headers. The only issue I have with that is how I can differentiate between the different versions of the **working file** (V1, V2, V3). One work-around is having to indicate the version and have the macro change the headers in first, but maybe someone knows a better work-around.

```
Sub CopyPasteBasedOnHeaders1()
   Dim SrcWs As Variant, TrgWs As Worksheet
   Dim Col As Long, TrgLastRw As Long, SrclastRw As Long, SrcLastCol As Long, TrgLastCol As Long
   Dim SrcRng As Range, TrgRng As Range, C As Range, Hd As String

   Set TrgWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

   SrcWs = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *.xls*", Title:="Select a File")
   If SrcWs <> False Then
       Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(SrcWs)
       Set SrcWs = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(2)

       SrcLastCol = SrcWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
       TrgLastCol = TrgWs.Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

       For Col = 1 To SrcLastCol
           Hd = SrcWs.Cells(1, Col).Value

           If Hd <> "" Then
               SrclastRw = SrcWs.Cells(Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row + 1
               Set SrcRng = SrcWs.Range(SrcWs.Cells(2, Col), SrcWs.Cells(SrclastRw, Col))

               With TrgWs.Range(TrgWs.Cells(1, 1), TrgWs.Cells(1, TrgLastCol))
                   Set C = .Find(Hd, LookIn:=xlValues)    'each column header is searched in trgWs

                   If Not C Is Nothing Then
                       TrgLastRw = TrgWs.Cells(Rows.Count, C.Column).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                       Set TrgRng = TrgWs.Cells(TrgLastRw, C.Column).Resize(SrcRng.Rows.Count, 1)
                       SrcRng.Copy Destination:=TrgRng
                   End If
               End With
           End If
       Next Col
   End If
End Sub
```

I hope someone is able to help me or guide me in the right direction. My expertise is limited to YouTube videos and some reading left and right.

Comment: `I'm however only interested in capturing the standard structure and ignore the rest.` In that case,

**1.** Open file in readonly mode. **2.** Delete the columns you do not need

Comment: Hello Siddharth. It's no issue doing any of these things by hand. I however want to automate the process and just elaborated on the state of the data that the macro needs to take into account. An user should click a button triggering the macro, select their working file and have the data extracted into their analytics file.

Comment: `Hello Siddharth. It's no issue doing any of these things by hand. I however want to automate the process` I meant it via code and not automatically....

Comment: So search the top row, and delete any columns that have no value. Then copy-paste based on a range? I guess that could work. Only not sure if I can also have the code close the opened working file **without** saving it. The user will still want to keep the added columns. Also not sure whether any of these operations become too heavy as the working files can get pretty large (5-8MB). The code I pasted should actually do exactly what I want, but I need it to copy from row 12 downward only and paste it from row 12 again. I need to change something to the files, but the macro works partly!

Comment: **1.** `So search the top row, and delete any columns that have no value.` Yes that is correct. If required, rearrange the columns in a specific order so that you do not have to copy specific ranges. Directly copy the rows.  **2.** `I can also have the code close the opened working file without saving it.` That is why I said open the file as readonly so that you do not accidently save it. **3.** `Also not sure whether any of these operations become too heavy as the working files can get pretty large (5-8MB).` I doubt it but you can try working with Arrays as well.

Comment: I've tried to get the sorting to run, but to no avail. Do you happen to have any code in hand that takes into account that columns might be added? I've tried to record a macro, but then it selects the range for me. If I can replace "A1:CF1" with the last column, I think I can get it. Unsure how to write that though as with the lastrow it's range("A1:CF" & LastRow). But how to do that with a column?

Comment: To find last column in row 1 you can use `lCol = ws.Cells(1, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` and then to get the name you can use `ColName = Split(Cells(, lCol).Address, "$")(1)` So `range("A1:CF" & LastRow)` can then be written as `range("A1:" & ColName " & LastRow)`. Alternative way to write it is `ws.Range(ws.Cells(1,1),ws.Cells(lRow,LCol))`